# List of a specific Custom Post Type in Custom Template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

My WP 3.6 has created a custom template using `register_post_type()` named `movie`. I inserted few `movie` via `Admin Dashboard > Movie`. For Permalink, I have set to Post Type, therefore, for example, `movie1` (instance of Custom Post Type `movie`), the URL is:

> http://example.com/wordpress/movie/movie1

If I want to show a list of `movie` with link `http://example.com/wordpress/movie/`, which custom template file has to be created?

I already have `single.php`, `single-movie.php` for displaying the `movie1`. But how about a list of `movie` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is the `archive-POST_TYPE.php` file, so in your case it would be `archive-movie.php`.
You find more information on that (and all the other templates) in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Secondly, you can just list your custom posts anywhere you want, using a separate query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    // maybe put some other settings here as well
);
$movies = new WP_Query($args);
if ($movies->have_posts()) {
    while ($movies->have_posts()) {
        $movies->the_post();
        // now work with `the_content`, `the_title` and the like...
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```